# rewrite .live after jQuery2 update

Tags: jquery

Upgrading from 1.7 to jQuery 2

having this function

```
$.fn.addFavorite = function(){
  var self = this;
  this.live('click', function(){
    // code
```

and thought there are 2 approaches

```
$.fn.addFavorite = function(){
  var self = this;
  $(document).on("click", this, function() {
```

or

```
$.fn.addFavorite = function(){
  var self = this;
  $(this).click(function() {
```

which is the more correct one?

---

the same goes for other plugin-extension-style, where we have

```
$(document).on("submit", this, function() {
```

vs

```
$(this).submit( function () {
```

Comment: Use first approach `$(document).on("click", this, function() {` for dynamic elements and second `$(this).click(function() {` for static elements

Comment: .on() for future elements. but if we go "plugin-extension-style" `$(selector).addFavorite() `then we alrady have the element so i can go with the straight click?